# How to align some lines under tabular?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am using `tabular`, and I would like to realize something like that:

```
word1     word2     word3
word4     longerword5
word6     word7     word8
```

So `word1,2,3,4,6,7,8` are well aligned, and I do not want `longerword5` to be taken into account for spacing in other rows. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Either change `longerword5` to `\multicolumn{2}{l}{longerword5}` to make it span over two columns (`{2}`), left aligned (`{l}`) or write it as `\rlap{longerword5}` so that its width is ignored.

Comment: @Martin: `\rlap` is a macro for the *cognoscenti*; a more orthodox LaTeX is `\makebox[0pt][l]{longerword5}`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the command `\multicolumn`. The command is defined by latex itself. So you don't need any packages.

The syntax of the command is:

```
\multicolumn{n}{<justification>}{<contents>}
```

n is the numbers of columns. The `<justification>` can be every known one like, r-l-c-p-m.

A small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}\hline
word in column 1 & word in column 2 & word in column 3 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{words over column 1 to 3}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How you can see the vertical rules have to set separately by multicolumn.

Comment: Maybe you could turn this into a slightly more helpful answer.

Comment: @Alan: I think a command like this doesn't need any explanation. In this case google is very useful.

Comment: depending on one's level of expertise, many things on this site don't need any explanation. But one of the purposes of the site is to become a repository for accurate knowledge (that's part of why answers are votable.) There is a lot of lousy information about LaTeX to be found via google, (even though in this case one might find good information easily.)  So why not spend the extra minute or so providing an example to make your answer more helpful to others than have this debate with me?

Comment: @Alan: Ok you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Either change `longerword5` to `\multicolumn{2}{l}{longerword5}` to make it span over two columns (`{2}`), left aligned (`{l}`) or write it as `\rlap{longerword5}` so that its width is ignored.

As egreg pointed out `\rlap{longerword5}` (a TeX macro) is equivalent to the LaTeX macro `\makebox[0pt][l]{longerword5}`. I personally don't think `\rlap` (lap to the right) is to complicated to be understood by beginners. Instead `\makebox[0pt][l]` seems to be more complicated.